# how add video on activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent

Hello I am new to android developement I am making an recipe app in that Im using firebase I have added Image and video to firebase and image is showing on activity but I dont know how to add video on activity please help

this is my activity where I want to show video I have taken a video view on xml

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView foodName,foodIngrediants,foodProcedure;//
ImageView foodImage;
VideoView foodVideo;
MediaController mediaController;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    foodName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    foodImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage2);
    foodVideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.ivVideo2);
    foodIngrediants = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Ingrediants);//
    foodProcedure = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Procedure);


    Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(mBundle!=null){

        foodName.setText(mBundle.getString("Name"));
        foodIngrediants.setText(mBundle.getString("Ingrediants"));//
        foodProcedure.setText(mBundle.getString("Procedure"));
        foodImage.setImageResource(mBundle.getInt("Image"));
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(mBundle.getString("Image"))
        .into(foodImage);


    }
}
}
```

this is my myAdapter in this I have added intent code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodViewHolder foodViewHolder, int i) {

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(myFoodList.get(i).getItemImage())
            .into(foodViewHolder.imageView);
    //foodViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(myFoodList.get(i).getItemImage());
    foodViewHolder.mTitle.setText(myFoodList.get(i).getItemName());
    foodViewHolder.mDescription.setText(myFoodList.get(i).getItemDescription());
    foodViewHolder.mPrice.setText(myFoodList.get(i).getItemPrice());

    foodViewHolder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Image",myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemImage());
            intent.putExtra("Video",myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemVideo());
            intent.putExtra("Name",myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemName());
            intent.putExtra("Ingrediants",myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemIngrediants());//
            intent.putExtra("Procedure",myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemProcedure());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

please tell me how to add video on that videoview

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Everything is working fine but I want to show a video in videoview in detailactivity which is coming through intent whise key is video

Comment: Have you tried something in code for that?

Comment: I tried to use mediacontroller